# How do I send the same header with every response in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to send the header "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" back with every response in my zend framework 2 application. How can I do that without explicitly coding it in every single controller method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the response object via the bootstrap:

**Module.php**

```
/**
 * On bootstrap event
 * 
 * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $headers = $e->getResponse()->getHeaders(); 
    $headers->addHeaderLine('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
}
```